# Reload page only if in first page of the pagination

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

i have this jquery code, ajax, whch helps me to do some pagination.

Now, i grab the data from a php file which has only some information printed.

The index file is this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function loading_show(){
            $('#loading').html("<img src='images/loading.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
        }
        function loading_hide(){
            $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
        }                
        function loadData(page){
            loading_show();                    
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "load_data.php",
                data: "page="+page,
                success: function(msg)
                {
                    $("#container").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                    {
                        loading_hide();
                        $("#container").html(msg);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
        loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
        $('#container .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
            var page = $(this).attr('p');
            loadData(page);

        });           

        });
    });
</script>
```

What i want to do is that, i want to reload the page only if i am on the first page, i mean, in pagination we have something like:

```
<- 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ->
```

I want to reload the content without refreshing only if i'm on the first page.
Can someone help me with that?
Thanks!

Comment: `if (page==1) { $.ajax({ ... }); }`

Comment: i understand the logic, i mean i get it how it should be, but i can't write the code for it, i don't even know where to put it in the above section and how to reload it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#container .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
     var page = $(this).attr('p');

     if(page === 1){
         setTimeout(function(){
             loadData(page);
     }, 2000);

    }
});
```

Here's a similar solution to the one already posted, but executed after 2 seconds. Change the second arg (milliseconds) to any value you want.

Comment: Thank you. I mainly just built on the what was already posted, and didn't quickly check said API like I should have.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('#container .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
     var page = $(this).attr('p');
     if(page == 1)
         loadData(page);

});
```

Comment: this prevents the page to go from one page to another, plus it isn't reloading the first page after x seconds..

Comment: @ossial no mention of `x seconds` in question. @Andy code does what your explanation asked for. Perhaps you should be more specific in question about behavior wanted

Comment: well, after implementing Andy's code i wasn't able to move from one page to another.. and yes, sorry i thought i did mention the fact of reloading without refreshing, only on the first page so i could get real time data....
i don't know if this is doable here though..